# can I access USB serial device(com5) in browser(web app) with javascript?

Tags: javascript, serial-port, progressive-web-apps, virtual-serial-port, com-port

I am working on a project. we have our USB device. so how can I open(access) my USB(refer to attached to the image to see what kind of port and device is.) data in the web app? and which "javascript APIs" do I have to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

If you want to use a serial port, you can use the Web Serial API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API

Comment: Current [browser support is limited to Chrome, Edge, and Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Serial_API#browser_compatibility).